# protected inheritance with template classes

Tags: c++

I am having some trouble with inheritance between template classes.  I started with a simple code that has a parent class and a child class that inherits that parent.  The child class is able to access the protected data member of the parent class.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

# define LENGTH 10

class Parent {
protected:
    int * array[LENGTH] = {NULL};
};


class Child : public Parent {
public:
    void addItem(int * item) {
        for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
            if (array[i] == NULL) {
                array[i] = item;
            }
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Child obj;
    int *temp = new int(5);
    obj.addItem(temp);
}
```

This compiles and runs just fine.  But then I try to do the same thing with template classes.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

# define LENGTH 10
template <typename T>
class Parent {
protected:
    T * array[LENGTH] = {NULL};
};

template <typename T>
class Child : public Parent<T> {
public:
    void addItem(T * item) {
        for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
            if (array[i] == NULL) {
                array[i] = item;
            }
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Child obj;
    int *temp = new int(5);
    obj.addItem(temp);
}
```

This second program does not compile, and I get an error that reads: 'array' was not declared in this scope.  I don't know why template classes change the way inheritance works.  Is there any way to use inheritance like this other than public get/set methods in the parent class?

Comment: Make it `Child<int> obj;`

Comment: Within `addItem`, use `this->array` everywhere you currently use `array`

Comment: You allocate a single int an set the value allways to 5. Why?

Comment: It looks like my question was already answered in another post.  Adding the lineusing
    Parent<T>::array;
will solve my problem.